# Do we need a 2017 moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Long-time moderator Joanne C recently (and, I think sadly and to all our loss) noted in her profile that she's leaving all of Stack Exchange, and I notice that she's no longer in the [moderators list](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). That leaves us with two moderators, and while jrista is still active on the site, not nearly as much as he used to be. Is it time for another election to add one or two more moderators?

(In any case, thanks for all of your work, both as a moderator and site contributor, Joanne.)

Comment: Are there any other graduated sites with only two moderators?

Comment: While it looks like she won't read it, I'd like to echo Matt's thanks above to Joanne. You've been a great moderator on this site, and I hope you come back.

Comment: The Community team is working on queuing an election for this community, yeah ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two mods is not enough, and I know they plan to hold an election soon.  Three mods is probably enough unless jrista doesn't plan to be all that active.

Answer (score 4):

I am more active now that I've been made aware of Joanne's choice to leave the community. This site is very self sufficient, and even with my increased visits, I am not seeing very many mod issues that need dealing with. If we really need a third mod, we can certainly ask for an election as well (we did that before and Mike was elected. ;))